# SCM Manager Issue With Base Url

Tags: svn, version-control

I installed **SCM Manager** and changed the base URL to an invalid URL. Now I cannot access the application web page. Where is the configuration for the Base URL in SCM Manager, so that I can correct the setting?

Comment: i have the same problem. any luck?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration file is config/config.xml and it is stored in the scm home directory (for the location of the home directory, please have a look at the faq). You have to stop your application and change the following from:

```
<force-base-url>true</force-base-url>
```

To:

```
<force-base-url>false</force-base-url>
```